# Elastic search Docker '#/elasticsearch/host' must use http

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, elasticsearch-docker

I am getting this error when trying to run elastic locally in docker without ssl

```
2024-02-14 10:58:44 Invalid config file (/usr/share/enterprise-search/config/enterprise-search.yml):
2024-02-14 10:58:44 The setting '#/elasticsearch/host' must use http if '#/elasticsearch/ssl/enabled' is 'false', but the given value is 'https://elasticsearch:9200'
```

Compose file

```yaml
version: "2.2"

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - elasticsearchdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - ${ES_PORT}:9200
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
      - ENTERPRISESEARCH_HOST=http://enterprisesearch:${ENTERPRISE_SEARCH_PORT}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}

  enterprisesearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/enterprise-search/enterprise-search:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - enterprisesearchdata:/usr/share/enterprise-search/config
    ports:
      - ${ENTERPRISE_SEARCH_PORT}:3002
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=enterprisesearch
      - secret_management.encryption_keys=[${ENCRYPTION_KEYS}]
      - allow_es_settings_modification=true
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - elasticsearch.host=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - elasticsearch.username=elastic
      - elasticsearch.password=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - elasticsearch.ssl.enabled=false
      - kibana.external_url=http://kibana:5601
      - xpack.security.authc.api_key.enabled=true
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}

volumes:
  elasticsearchdata:
    driver: local
  enterprisesearchdata:
    driver: local
  kibanadata:
    driver: local
```

elasticsearch.host=http://elasticsearch:9200 is set to http